# Chicken or Egg with Resolve, Device Ready and Retrieving Data using SQLite Plugin

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

In my **Angular/Ionic App**, I am trying to redirect an user to the state `Setup` when he opens the app for the first time, and has not setup his default account settings yet. To do this,

- I use a database SQLite (from brodysoft in Phonegap Build consumed by ngCordova)
- This database will contain a table `Variables` if and only if the the user has setup his account
- Using UI-router, I attach a resolve function to the first state (`Auth`), see also below
- The resolve function `setupResolve()` tries to retrieve the data from the table `Variables`, upon *success* it resolves the state 'Auth', upon *failure* it redirects the user to the state `Setup`

Here comes the issue:

- To open the SQLite database and perform queries (such as SELECT), the device needs to be ready. In Ionic, this corresponds to wrapping the opening of the database and the queries inside the function `$ionicPlatform.ready(){}` - see a tutorial [here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/).
- However, the device will not be ready until all resolve functions are resolved.
- But again, in order to resolve, the platform needs to be ready such that SQLite can be reached, which only can happen when all functions are resolved.

So as you see you get in a Chicken or Egg situation. Concretely, in my code below, the function ionicPlatform.ready() is not firing when opening the app on my device.

The strange thing is that it works fine on Google Chrome, but my guess is that the ionicPlatform.ready() is bypassed in the browser, or that there are other criteria.

```
// 
  // I-1
  self.openDb = function(method) {

    //
    var qOpen = $q.defer();
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      // ** NEVER REACHED WHEN USED IN RESOLVE CONTEXT **

      // Open Db
      if(window.cordova) {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("starter.db");
      } else {
        db = window.openDatabase("starter.db", "1.0", "My app", 1024 * 1024 * 100);
      }

      // Create Tables
      self.createTables().then(function(){
        qOpen.resolve(true);
      }, function(error){
        qOpen.reject(error);
      })
    })
    return qOpen.promise;
  };
```

**state auth, code in .config**

*Note: the setupResolve function calls the function openDb()*

```
.state('auth', {
    url: '/auth',
    templateUrl: 'templates/single-auth.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl',  
    resolve: {
      setupResolve: setupResolve
    }
  })
```

Comment: I almost scrolled complete page twice. Posting a Plunker will actually allow us to review the issue before jumping on the code.

Comment: Thanks might do that, if interested then I recommend to only focus on the part with openDb and Query, as basically the issue is that I am trying to resolve opening a database and retrieving data. However, for this data to be retrieves, the platform needs to be ready, but the platform is only ready when everything is resolved, so you get a chicken or egg situation.

Comment: I have rewritten my question, please have a look and see whether it is more clear now.